# Проблема с base64 в font-face

Tags: html, css, шрифты, base64

Шрифт [Roboto](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto) вставлен с использованием base64:

```css
p {
  font-family: 'roboto';
  src: url(data:font-woff;base64,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) format('woff');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<p>Test</p>
```

Отображается в Firefox, но сегодня перестал работать в Chrome (ранее все работало).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правило [@font-face](http://htmlbook.ru/css/font-face) позволяет определить настройки шрифтов, а также загрузить специфичный шрифт на компьютер пользователя.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'roboto';
  src: local('roboto'), url('data:application/x-font-woff;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAGC...') format('woff');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

p { font-family: 'roboto', serif }
```

Пример http://jsfiddle.net/f6L2or4h/2/ (в ответе пример весь не помещяется)

Comment: @Riskey, проблема не в том, чтобы заменить `font-woff` на `application/x-font-woff`, а в том, что вы свойство `src` применяете не там где надо. Оно применимо в правиле `@font-face`, но ни как не в стиле для элемента `p`.

Comment: Я изменил _font-woff_ на _application/x-font-woff_ и все заработало